# Array formula to check for blanks

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a google sheet with customer orders.

- Column A contains the order number
- The next four columns contain various data, filled at various stages of the order.  (Columns B through E)
- In Column F I'd like to have an array formula that checks when the orders are complete, i.e. each column in a row is filled in, for all rows that contain an order number.

Therefore, if A2:E2 are all filled with data, then in F2 it should state "Complete".

I've tried:

```
COUNTA
ISBLANK
AND
OR
COUNTBLANK
```

All formula work on a row by row basis, but not when entered in an arrayformula.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(and(LEN(A2:A),COUNTA($B2:E)=0)="True","Complete","There be blanks afoot")
```

Or

```
=ArrayFormula(If(LEN(A3:A),IF(COUNTBLANK($B2:$E)>0,"Blanks","No Blanks"),""))
```

Test sheet can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mNIGRh910k_q9J2P6mzv9q-h-me3zxbCWeJ2mcaFsXQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"Status"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", IF(MMULT(
 IF(B2:E<>"", 1, 0), {1;1;1;1})=4, "Complete", "Still blanks"), ))}
```

[image: 0]